# Using JQuery - preventing form from submitting

Tags: jquery, forms

How do I prevent a form from submitting using jquery?

I tried everything - see 3 different options I tried below, but it all won't work:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 

            //option A
            $("#form").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            //option B
            $("#form").submit(function(e){
                stopEvent(e);
            });

            //option C
            $("#form").submit(function(){
                return false;
            });
    });
```

What could be wrong?

Update - here is my html:

```
    <form id="form" class="form" action="page2.php" method="post"> 
       <!-- tags in the form -->
       <p class="class2">
           <input type="submit" value="Okay!" /> 
       </p>
    </form>
```

Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: Show your HTML because there is nothing wrong with preventDefault or return false as you posted it, other than your selector being totally wrong.

Comment: `return false;` after the `.submit()` worked for me! I was having the same issue

Comment: If there is a JavaScript error occuring in the handler the `e.preventDefault();` code is not reached / executed.

Answer (score 324, accepted):

Two things stand out:

- It possible that your form name is not `form`.  Rather refer to
  the tag by dropping the #.
- Also the `e.preventDefault` is the correct JQuery syntax, e.g.

  ```
      //option A
      $("form").submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
      });
  ```

Option C should also work. I am not familiar with option B

A complete example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
         $(document).ready(function() {
            //option A
            $("form").submit(function(e){
                alert('submit intercepted');
                e.preventDefault(e);
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="http://google.com" method="GET">
          Search <input type='text' name='q' />
          <input type='submit'/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Something else is wrong. I am using this technique on a daily basis. Best guess would be that there are JavaScript errors on the page, perhaps check it with FireBug?

Comment: @LucyWeatherford, I have updated my answer with a sample that works.  Maybe you spot someting.

Comment: In your update html I noticed that you have class attribute for your form.  Change your JQuery selector from `$('#form')` to `$('.form')` for class attributes.

Comment: nice catch, but i had an id as well, i just deleted it meanwhile and changed the selector to ("form") as you suggested. Anyhow I tried now (".form") and it didn't work either...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7906/discussion-between-philip-fourie-and-lucy-weatherford)

Comment: thanks! I ended up using your code on the same page, and it worked, still unsure what was wrong though, but it's all good now. thanks!

Comment: 2 things that may have solved this: 1. I moved the js to the same page (maybe something was getting in the way). 2. I deleted various other js I had on the page which may have been getting in the way as well. Now it works. yay!

Comment: Here it is working for me using e: function(e) and e.preventDefault(e); how does "e" work´s it stands for exception?

Comment: @ÂngeloRigo e is simply the name you give to the parameter, in this case it's the submit event.

Comment: thing is its working for restriction, but it don't when i want to submit the from

Comment: I have tried with your solution, but form is still being submitted.

Answer (score 43):

You probably have few forms o the page and using $('form').submit() adds this event to the first occurrence of the form on your page. Use class selector instead, or try this:

```
$('form').each(function(){
    $(this).submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('it is working!');
        return  false;
    })
})
```

or better version of it:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('it works!');
    return  false;
});
```

Comment: In my case, returning false was a key.

Answer (score 26):

To prevent default/prevent form submission use

```
e.preventDefault();
```

To stop event bubbling use

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

To prevent form submission 'return false' should work too.

Comment: See this answer because jQuery handles these differently.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: Check this to understand event bubling http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: The [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) API states: "Returning false from an event handler will automatically call `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`.  A `false` value can also be passed for the handler as a shorthand for `function(){ return false; }`."

Answer (score 10):

I also had the same problem. I also had tried what you had tried. Then I change my method not to use jquery but by using "onsubmit" attribute in the form tag.

```
<form onsubmit="thefunction(); return false;">
```

It works.

But, when I tried to put the false return value only in `thefunction()`, it doesn't prevent the submitting process, so I must put `return false;` on `onsubmit` attribute.

Comment: It is the difference between `false;` and `return false;`. You'd need to have `onsubmit="return thefunction();"`

Comment: This works well. but if we are using Content Security Policy, these inline scripts are not allowed

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I solved this way (not elegant but it works):

```
$('#form').attr('onsubmit','return false;');
```

And it has the advantage, in my opinion, that you can revert the situation any time you want:

```
$('#form').attr('onsubmit','return true;');
```

Comment: Maybe it would be a little more comfortable to just remove the attribute when reverting the form submit prevention `$('#form').removeAttr('onsubmit');`

Answer (score 5):

Attach the event to the submit element not to the form element.
For example in your html do like this

```
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You may simply check if the form is valid if yes run submit logic otherwise show error.

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" class="form" action="page2.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="check-validity" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="check-validity" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="check-validity" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="check-validity" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="check-validity" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="check-validity" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="check-validity" value="" />

    <input type="submit" value="Okay!" />
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var isFormValid = true;

        function checkFormValidity(form){
            isFormValid = true;
            $(form).find(".check-validity").each(function(){
                var fieldVal = $.trim($(this).val());
                if(!fieldVal){
                    isFormValid = false;
                }
            });
        }


        //option A
        $("#form").submit(function (e) {
            checkFormValidity("#form");
            if(isFormValid){
                alert("Submit Form Submitted!!! :D");
            }else{
                alert("Form is not valid :(");
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, you can do the following:

1. Use the native form submit event with a Submit button, while preventing the event from firing, then
2. Check the form Valid property.

This can be implemented as following:

1. HTML:

   ```
   <form id="yourForm">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Save"/>
   </form>
   ```
2. JavaScript:

   ```
   $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).valid()) {  
             alert('Success!');
        }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#form')` looks for an element with `id="form"`.

`$('form')` looks for the form element

Answer (score 1):

You forget the form id, and it works

```
$('form#form').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('prevent submit');             
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When I am using `<form>` tag without the attribute `id="form"` and call it by its tag name directly in jquery it works with me.
your code in html file :

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
```

and in Jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('form').submit(function(evt){
          evt.preventDefault();// to stop form submitting
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

This also appears to work and may be slightly simpler:

```
$('#Form').on('submit',function(){
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The information is missing how to prevent the form submit and then **revert the situation**, i. e. allow the form submit later on.

Here is an example:

```
var savebtn_clicked;

$('form#commentform').submit( function(e) {
    return savebtn_clicked;
});

$('#savebtn').click( function() {
    savebtn_clicked = true;
    $('#form#commentform').submit();
});
```

In my case every button fired the form. With the code above I could control which button allowed the form to be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

**Prevent** submitting form data and then **release**.

```
  $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('Ok');
   $( this ).unbind( 'submit' ).submit(); // Release 
  });
```

- *It's working*

Answer (score 0):

```
// Prevent form submission
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

from here: https://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/ (interesting page on submit types)

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
$("form").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var error = "";

    if ($("#subject").val() == "") {
        error += "The subject filed is required.<br>";
    }

    if ($("#message").val() == "") {
        error += "The content feed is required.";
    }

    if (error != "") {
        $("#error").html("<div class= 'alert alert-danger' role ='alert'><p><strong>There were error(s) in your form </strong></p>" + error + "</div>");
    } else {
        $("form").unbind("submit").submit();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).