# How to reset default form behaviour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I answered my own question because I was an idiot. :)

---

I've bound a function with jQuery `submit()` to a form that prevents the default behaviour (with `event.preventDefault()` and `return false`) so that it can perform the client-side validation. The script doesn't actually do any form submission (it leaves that to another script).

Now I want to remove the event and revert to the default form behaviour. I need to actually post the data (without AJAX) to another page/website, but I still want to validate it using the script I wrote.

I have considered duplicating the form HTML and submitting it that way, but that would be a last resort.

I have tried using `unbind('submit')` however that did nothing. I'm guessing it actually unbinds the default behaviour too.

*What can I do? Is the default behaviour still bound to the form, just not in use?*

**Note:** I can't modify the validation script nor can I unbind that specific function that prevents the default behaviour.

Source-code available on request, however most of the code is irrelevant, so I will only post snippets (shown below).

```
function _preventDefaults() {
    //Prevent form from submitting (until we validate it)...
    $('#myform').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: What is `_Form`? (guess it's `$("form")`)

Comment: @Mics You are correct. I'll edit the code to show that.

Comment: Is `#myform` correct? Isn't there many forms?

Comment: @Mics There is only one form that can be named anything.

Comment: Try using `$('#myform').off('submit')`. Also, you're not going to remove any default behavior by using `.unbind()` or `.off()`.

Comment: Similar problem to yours, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9347286/924943)

Comment: I found what was happening. See my own answer to this question.

Comment: Replacing the form with a clone of itself will remove any dynamically added listeners.

Comment: @RobG Yeah I said in the question that I've considered doing that but it would be a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

```
$('#myform').find('INPUT,TEXTAREA,BUTTON').attr('disabled', 'yes');
```

I wanted to grey out the fields and prevent the user from changing the values (because I'm OCD like that). I completely forgot the browser will not send inputs that are disabled.

Sorry for wasting your time everyone. Next time I'll post the code that unbinds the event, which would show you what I've just found.

Edit: What's worse is that I knew the form was submitting because I was being redirected to the `action` location. gg.

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass the bound event using the native method.

```
$("#myform").get().submit();
```

Alternatively, you can create a new form and copy the inputs from the old one into it.

```
$("<form></form").attr("action","somepage.php").append($("#myform :input")).submit();
```

Since you're letting it redirect, it shouldn't matter that they aren't in the old form anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
_Form.unbind('submit');
```

If you're using a newer version of jQuery you can also do:

```
_Form.off('submit');
```

Comment: I tried unbinding `submit` but nothing changed. I could be doing it wrong, or doing that will actually unbind all `submit` events (including the default). _Updated question mentioning I've tried this_.

Comment: You can't remove the default form behavior (if I'm following you right). I set up a little demo. If you don't calll $('#myForm').unbind('submit') it just logs and sits there. http://jsbin.com/ediyel/2/edit

Comment: Thanks for the jsbin! I'll give it a shot on my end.