# Prevent submit of form if criteria met

Tags: jquery, if-statement

The script is displaying the quantity of empty fields when clicked, but it's also submitting when has empty fields.

I need to do not submit if empty fields > 0

Form:

```
<form action="apostar.php" method="post" id="submitBet">
...
...
...
</form>
```

jQuery Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bt_bet').click(function(){
        var emptyFields = $('input[type=text]:empty').length;
        if (emptyFields == 0) {         
            var confirma = confirm('Confirma as apostas?');
            if (confirma) {
                $("#submitBet").submit();
            } else {
                //case cancel, do something..
            }
        } else {
            alert ('There are ' + emptyFields + ' empty fields.');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: changed the title as there is no such thing as a Jquery if statement. Just pre-empting some negative comments!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using JQuery - preventing form from submitting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347282/using-jquery-preventing-form-from-submitting)

Comment: why don't you use HTML <input> required Attribute, if all you want is not to submit form if inputs are empty?

Comment: I would not use :empty is this case, it's unsafe like this case http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/SSnLn/ it will always return the same number

Comment: @sanki, probably because it's very badly supported http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

Comment: @sanki, yes that's because it's very badly supported, and all fields are extremely important.

Comment: @Anton, what do you recommend instead of :empty?

Comment: probably $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){...} and add everytime there is an empty input and alert the int. check this out http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/SSnLn/2/ @Tiago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent the default action of the click event by calling [.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bt_bet').click(function(e){
        var emptyFields = $('input[type=text]:empty').length;
        if (emptyFields == 0) {         
            var confirma = confirm('Confirma as apostas?');
            if (confirma) {
                $("#submitBet").submit();
            } else {
                //case cancel, do something..
            }
        } else {
            alert ('There are ' + camposVazios + ' empty fields.');
            e.preventDefault()
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Answer = e.preventDefault().
First time using this function hehe. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should check out e.preventDefault() (http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

What this does is it basically overrides the default action of the element, in this case what I'm guessing is a submit button.