# Form is submitted even after using e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form which checks for the ifsc code of before form submission, The api returns "failure" if wrong ifsc is given. If the response is a failure, the form shouldn't be submitted. I used `e.preventDefault(e)` but it didn't help.

```
$('#corporate-signup').on('submit',function(e){

    var ifsc_code = $('#ifsc-code').val();
    var api_url = 'http://api.techm.co.in/api/v1/ifsc/'+ifsc_code;
    $.get(api_url, function(data, status){

       if (data.status === "failure") {
           $('.bank-details').addClass('no-ifsc').text(data.message);
           e.preventDefault(e);
       }

       else{
           $('#corporate-signup').submit()
           }

    });


});
```

I don't know what is the mistake here. I have also tried to `return false` instead of `preventDefault()` but even it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using JQuery - preventing form from submitting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347282/using-jquery-preventing-form-from-submitting)

Comment: try `return false`. if it still does submit the condition in `if` fails .. any demo page would help

Comment: check if you dont have js errors before `preventDefault`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that because you use an async function and don't return false, it goes ahead and submits before waiting for an answer - it doesn't know to wait for the callback.

Since you manually submit inside the async callback, try to add `e.preventDefault(e);` after the `$.get`:

```
var shouldSubmit = false;
$('#corporate-signup').on('submit',function(e){
    if (!shouldSubmit) {
        // First time entering, this won't submit due to line below
        e.preventDefault(e);
        var ifsc_code = $('#ifsc-code').val();
        var api_url = 'http://api.techm.co.in/api/v1/ifsc/'+ifsc_code;
        $.get(api_url, function(data, status){

           if (data.status === "failure") {
               $('.bank-details').addClass('no-ifsc').text(data.message);
           }

           else{
               shouldSubmit = true;
               $('#corporate-signup').submit()
           }

        });
    }
});
```

**Edit:** added `shouldSubmit` boolean, since otherwise it would keep hitting `e.preventDefault(e)` and never submitting. Upon a successful result from the async request, you can set it to true and resubmit.

Comment: i tried your method, it doesn't submit the form at all

Comment: That's actually good, that means it prevented it at first. Now you just gotta make sure it enters the `else` clause and that your selector finds it. `submit()` should be working.

Comment: Actually - I know why that happens. Your maual `submit()` just triggers the above code all over again. Lemme edit.

Comment: Added a boolean to keep track of your state. See edit.

Comment: The above code made it as an infinite loops and the page crashed

Comment: Yes noticed that after I editted, but updated it again. Lemme remake that, seems buggy still.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#corporate-signup').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ifsc_code = $('#ifsc-code').val();
    var api_url = 'http://api.techm.co.in/api/v1/ifsc/'+ifsc_code;
    $.get(api_url, function(data, status){

       if (data.status === "failure") {
           $('.bank-details').addClass('no-ifsc').text(data.message);
       }
       else{
           $('#corporate-signup')[0].submit() // bypass jQuery bound event
       }
    });
});
```