# How to disable a form on submit using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to disable a form once I submit it. I tried this but it doesn't disable the form:

```
$( "#myform" ).prop("disabled", true);
```

I am using jQuery/php/ajax. When the user clicks submit the submit button is disabled and a spinner displays in the button. Server side validation is done and errors are displayed or an email is sent and success message is displayed. In that time when the spinner is going, I don't want the user to be able to change anything on the form like click another radio button for example. The form is pretty quick but you never know..

Comment: Disable a "form"? Do you mean disable the form's submit button? Please post a [mcve] and any error messages you're getting.

Comment: The html `form` element does not contain/support a `disabled` attribute.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain properly. I am using jQuery/php/ajax. When the user clicks submit the submit button is disabled and a spinner displays in the button. Server side validation is done and errors are displayed or an email is sent and success message is displayed. In that time when the spinner is going, I don't want the user to be able to change anything on the form like click another radio button for example. The form is pretty quick but you never know..

Comment: This question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347282/using-jquery-preventing-form-from-submitting

Comment: Change your spinner into a modal that prevents the user from clicking under it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can "disable" a `<form>` element.  But if its contents are wrapped in a `<fieldset>` then you can easily disable that:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST" action="test.php">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <input type="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And:

```
$( "#myform fieldset" ).prop("disabled", true);
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/qnxp7b23/)