# issue with my form submission and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have called a jquery function in form onSubmit
if the status is false, then don't allow form submission
but currently, it is going to submitted page

here is my whole code
php form

```
echo "<form name='formulaire' id='my_form' method='POST' action='presale_pay.php' onSubmit='return veriftel();'>";
echo "<input type='text' name='promocode' placeholder='Enter Promo Code' id='promo'><div id='result'></div>";

echo "<p> <input type='submit' value='CONFIRM'></form>";
```

promocheck.php

```
<?php
include("include/control.php");


if (SessionValide ($session, $bd))
{
   $data=array();
    $promo=$_POST["promo"];

    $party=$bd->ligneSuivante($bd->execRequete("SELECT * FROM promocodes WHERE promocode='$promo' AND used_nbr<=valid_nbr"));
  if(!empty($party))
  {

   $data["status"]=true;
   $data["percentage"]=$party["percentage"];

  }
 else {
       $data["status"]=false;
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
}
?>

function veriftel(e)


    {

            $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'promocheck.php',
            data:{promo:$("#promo").val()}, 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

             if(data.status==false)
             {
                $("#result").html("<font color=red>Invalid promocode</font>");
            return false;

             }
             else 
             {
                 return true;
             }
            }
          });
}
```

please help me to prevent form submit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using JQuery - preventing form from submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347282/using-jquery-preventing-form-from-submitting)

Comment: @pradeep if you have any solution for this?

Comment: see the above link

Comment: i tried that,its not working thats why posted

Comment: Please post the HTML and the code where you set the event on the button.

Comment: this is not a well formated question

Comment: @EddyYoung  i updated my code

Comment: @Geomorillo you have any solution for me?

Comment: i did not understand it please explain better

Comment: @Geomorillo edited for better understanding

Comment: the answer that padeep gave you should solve your problem why dont use an event for trigering the submit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170433/discussion-between-susana-and-geomorillo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should work like this

```
function veriftel(e)
{
e.preventDefault(); 
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
async: false, 
url: 'promocheck.php',
data:{promo:$("#promo").val()}, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
     if(data.status==false)
     {
        $("#result").html("<font color=red>Invalid promocode</font>");
        console.log("false");
      return false;

     }
     else 
     {
         console.log("true");
         return true;
     }
    }

  });
```

}

also the php code should pass the event to the function

```
echo "<form name='formulaire' id='my_form' method='POST' action='presale_pay.php' onSubmit='return veriftel(event);'>";
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the following ajax call is asynchronous one. Your code will not wait till you get response from the server, hence the function returns before the completion of ajax call and response.

To avoid the following problem, you'll have to make your ajax call synchronous. Add `aysnc:false` to make it syncronous

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    async: false, //syncronous call
    url: 'promocheck.php',
    data:{promo:$("#promo").val()}, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

    }
```

Please note that making the call synchronous will cause the javascript execution to freeze in the webpage.

Comment: yes that may solve the issue i did not think of that

Comment: @sandesh still have issue