# jQuery - click on input type submit

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following:

```
<input type="submit" class="form-control submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" />
```

Once the user clicks this button above, I want to handle it with jQuery script. How can I do it in the  section?

SOLVED

Comment: You'll need to create a function that is called on click. And because you have used `input type="submit"`, you'll need to pass the event into the function, and prevent it with `.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using JQuery - preventing form from submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347282/using-jquery-preventing-form-from-submitting)

Comment: @ObsidianAge thanks.