# When to use return false or event.preventdefault()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am bit confuse on this Javascript function

**When to use return false or event.preventdefault() ?**

I'm working on my first web app, and I want user to completely enter the required input in my forms

I have read some article about this, googling, surfing everywhere, some says return false, and other side says event.preventdefault()

ex 
`if (InputA == '' || inputA == 0) {event.preventdefault()}`

`or if (InputA == '' || inputA == 0) {return false}`

What is the different ? 
Is this will completely stop the form from submitting inputed value to DB ?

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks !

Comment: Thank you sir, and what do we do as web dev after this javascript function ? 
Should we show some error notification in forms  ? with css n text ?
Or we refresh the page ?

I am really got confused here (@_@")

Comment: and 1 other point, I used disabled prop HTML properties in my forms

ex if a true, prop disabled else prop false

is that okay ??

Comment: You should show errors regarding the missing data in that form.

Comment: You should not just scatter `return false`s and `e.preventDefault()`s all over your script. You use them when there's a need to use them. And when there will be a need, you'll also know what to do afterwards,

Comment: I use this `disabled="false"` 

so if the user already complete the requirement, my jquery code will `disabled="true"`

is that okay ??

Comment: Please ask a more specific question, as it is, it's hard to say what exactly you're needing, perhaps a full tutorial of DOM events, functions, and form validation, which all are more or less separated features.

Comment: i found my answer here [using-jquery-preventing-form-from-submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347282/using-jquery-preventing-form-from-submitting)

Comment: thank you all for viewing my post and tried to help me, I really really appreciate you all

big thanks !