# How to validate form elements for white space before sending it using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to validate form elements before sending it using AJAX request. It checks for error, but form gets submitted.

**My code:**

```
$('#accountFormAddEdit').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($('#account').val() == "")
        {
          alert("Account name is required");
        } else {
          $.ajax({
            url: '<?= base_url() ?>controller/method',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: $('#accountFormAddEdit').serialize(),
            beforeSend:function(){
              $('#submit').val("Saving");
              $('#accountForm').modal('hide');
            },
            success:function(data){
              $('#accountFormAddEdit')[0].reset();
              $('#accountForm').modal('hide');
            },
                    dataType: 'JSON',
          });
        }
        location.reload();
      });
```

I'm using a `HTML Modal` to show form And `PHP Codeigniter`.

When I submit the form `location.reload()` won't refresh the page, to get the result back I use to refresh the page.

So how to check for white space and prevent the form data submission and get the response without refresh?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347282/using-jquery-preventing-form-from-submitting)

Comment: try timming your variable before checking as if($.trim($('#account').val()) == "") to avoid form submission with whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

when there are no values then return false, use the following function:-

```
 $('#accountFormAddEdit').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#account').val() == ""){
      alert("Account name is required");
      return false;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
       url: '<?= base_url() ?>controller/method',
       method: 'POST',
       dataType: 'JSON',
       data: $('#accountFormAddEdit').serialize(),
       beforeSend:function(){
         $('#submit').val("Saving");
         $('#accountForm').modal('hide');
       },
       success:function(data){
         $('#accountFormAddEdit')[0].reset();
         $('#accountForm').modal('hide');
         location.reload();
       },
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to place `location.reload();` inside the success function or after `alert("Account name is required");` to prevent refresh event if you check for the white space