# Ajax called page with button not triggering modal window with form variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have this following `Ajax` call which is trying to get some data in certain intervals

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  x();

  function x() {
    var FD = new FormData($('form')[0]);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "qaVtagAjax.php",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      data: FD,
      success: function(result) {
        $("#inputFieldDisplay").html(result);
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
  setInterval(x, 5000);

});

$("#assignQaOa").click(function() {
  //            trigger modal
});
```

Content of the `Ajax` call page `qaVtagAjax.php` as below

```
echo '<form method="post"> <div class="card" style="position: relative; border-color: black; !important ">
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" name= "srNum" id="srNum" value = "someValue" hidden>
        <div class="col-sm"><button class="btn-primary modalButton" type="submit" name = "assignQaOa" id = "assignQaOa" title="Click to assign to some operator">Assign</button></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<br>';
```

As you can see there is a `button` in the `form` called `assignQaOa`. I want to trigger a modal window by clicking this button as show earlier

```
$("#assignQaOa").click(function() {
  //trigger modal by doing Eg: $('#myModal').modal('show');
  alert("Modal window showing");
});
```

As a first step, I tried to alert some message. But nothing is happening when I click the button. Does anyone have some idea why this way?

NB: Actual `qaVtagAjax.php` file has more `html` and php contents. Those are working correctly. So I simplified that codes for understanding the problem.

**Edit 1**

Following is the modal codes that I am using from `bootstrap`

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <input type="text" id="tagSerial" name="tagSerial" hidden>
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also I edited the button click code as below based on the suggestion. This time if I gave a simple alert, it is working. But modal is not showing

```js
$(document).on("click", "#assignQaOa", function() {
  //Alert is working. Eg: alert("some message");
  $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show'); //This is not working
});
```

**Edit 2**

Some post suggested the possibility that two time `bootstrap.js` was typed in the document. But for my case, it is not the case too. I only typed it once and I am using as below

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

`<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Does anyone know why this happening? As I mentioned in comments, if I removed the class `fade` from modal, then modal will show for a split second with this `$('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');` code

**Edit 3**
By doing `e.preventDefault()`, I am able to stop the form submission and show modal successfully. But now I have an element in the modal window that supposed to get some `$_POST` values from form submission. How can I get that `$_POST` value in the modal at this situation? My `Javascript` code as below

```js
$(document).on("click", "#assignQaOa", function(e) {
  $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
  $('#tagSerial').val($("#srNum").val());
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

The following is the element in the modal window

`<input type="text" id="tagSerial">`

Comment: change `$("#assignQaOa").click(function() ` to `$(document).on("click","#assignQaOa",function() {` and see if that works

Comment: @Swati It is showing the alert now. But when I tried to trigger modal, it is not working. I will update my question with the modal codes too

Comment: Is the modal loaded when the page is loaded? If it is being generated, then you might need to refer to the object by class rather than `id` value (i.e. `$('.modal.fade).modal('show');`)

Comment: @AaronMorefield Yes. modal is loaded when the page where I do `Ajax` calling. I tried to replace this `$('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');`  with your suggested code `$('.modal.fade').modal('show');`. But it is not working. But when I remove the class `fade` from `modal` and then used this `$('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');`, it is showing for a split second and then vanish. Do you have some idea?

Comment: Ooh! Check the parameters of the “modal” function in the Bootstrap framework. Maybe you need to call a “fade in” rather than “show”

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h The modal here seems to like the "Toggle" rather than the "Show"

Comment: This is not using `jQuery` right? I think it is just using the `data-target` and `data-toggle` in the button. Somehow it is not working in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trial and errors, I found issue was due to I am using `type = submit` for the `button`. When I changed `type = button`, modal triggered and showed correctly. But I am still puzzled why when I used `type = submit` and removed the class `fade`, modal showing for a split second. Probably there is a work around to show it correctly too. I hope some expert from stack overflow can find out and tell me the problem.

Anyway I still couldn't use this `type = button` for my scenario due to I need to get the values from a form submission when this button clicked. If use `type = button`, I cannot submit and get the values of the form through a `$_POST` method.

**Edit 1**

After got help from stack overflow member @Swati, realized that submit will refresh the page and that is why when used submit, modal is showing only for a split second. With her help I modified the code as below and able to solve my problem

```js
$(document).on("click", "#assignQaOa", function(e) {
  $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
  var sr = $(this).closest(".card-body").find("input[name='srNum']").val();
  $('#tagSerial').val(sr);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

The above code will stop form submission. Also it will grab the input field `srNum` value and show it in the modal even without submitting form.

Comment: because `type="submit"` will submit your `form` and do a refresh.. that's the reason it was showing your alert and then disappearing .So, even if you write click handler for your button then also it will get submit.Now , to overcome this  you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9347302/10606400) answer .

Comment: Also you can manually submit your `form` once user close modal use `$("form").submit()` .

Comment: @Swati When use `e.preventDefault();`, it works even with `type=submit`. But I want to show a variable that is getting from form submission in the modal window. But now since form is not submitting, it is not showing. Any way to get the variable and show in the form?

Comment: @Swati Please see the **Edit 3**

Comment: does on submit here `new FormData($('form')[0])` ? does that data is available which you need to show in modal?

Comment: @Swati Since the form is generated by `Ajax` and it is within a `form`, that could be available. yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217128/discussion-between-swati-and-anu).