# How do i encrypt password before send to php script?

Tags: javascript

I want to send the password encrypted to the server side script, and after match the pasword encrypted with the password on the database, if the passords match, redirect the user to the home page.

My Jquery function:

```
jQuery('#login_form').submit(function(){
  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append('login', $('#lg-user').val());
  form_data.append('password', CryptoJS.MD5($('#lg-password').val()));

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "processa.php",
    data: dados,
    success: function( data )
    {
      alert( data );
    }
  });
  
  return false;
});
```

The form:

```
                    <form action="" id="login_form" method="post">
                        <?php  
                            session_start();
                            if (isset($_SESSION['message']))
                            {
                                echo $_SESSION['message'];
                                unset($_SESSION['message']);
                            }
                        ?>
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" 
                        placeholder="usuario">      
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group form-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" 
                        placeholder="senha">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn login_btn">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

The problem is that everytime i send the form, the page reload.

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: "The problem is that everytime i send the form, the page reload" - so this has nothing to do with encrypting passwords or PHP? If you just want to prevent the page reload... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347282/using-jquery-preventing-form-from-submitting

Comment: Don't encrypt passwords with JS, use https connection instead.

Comment: if the page is https, you don't need this, but regardless, MD5 suffers collisions, so I wouldn't use it as a way to authenticate users ... like ... ever.

Comment: The console does not show ant errors,but I want that when I submit the form, be redirected to the home page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is highly insecure.

By encrypting it client-side and matching what it sent with the DB, you are sending the data that "proves" the user is who they say they are to the server, so if someone were to get hold the database they would know what to send.

Also, MD5 is *far* too weak to secure a password today.

---

To keep the password safe in transmission to the server: Use HTTPS.

To keep the passwords in your database safe: hash them server-side as described in the [Safe Password Hashing FAQ](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) in the PHP manual.

---

To stop the regular form submission when you use the `submit` event to intercept it and use Ajax:

1. Capture the event object
2. Call `preventDefault` on it

Such:

```
jQuery('#login_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
```

Comment: While I agree with you, if someone is able to get hold of the database it is already a bit too late to start enforcing security measures

Comment: @gbalduzzi the purpose behind securing passwords in your database is to prevent secondary attack vectors for other services the users might have. EI: the users email provider might have the same password as they registered with your website. This could make for a secondary attack vector to the users personal email. Proper storage isn't for your benefit, it's for your users.