# Can't not enter a correct page when I clicked login button

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Here is the login function.

```
@RequestMapping("dologin")
@ResponseBody
public boolean dologin(@RequestParam("username") String username,
                       @RequestParam("password")String password, User user, Model model, HttpSession session
, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    user = userService.login(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
    Boolean flag ;
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    System.out.println("dologin");
    if(userService.login(username,password) != null)
    {
        model.addAttribute("username", username);
        session.setAttribute("user",user);
        flag =  true;
    } else {
        
        flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Here is the login form

```
<form class="register-form" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="username" id="name" onkeyup="validate()"/>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" id="pw1" /><span id="tips" class="message"></span>
        <input type="password" placeholder="confirm password" id="pw2" onkeyup="validate()"/>
        <button type="submit" id="register" value="register" disabled="disabled">register</button>
        <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">login</a></p>
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    $("#loginBtn").click(function() {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"dologin",
            data:{"username" : username,
                    "password" : password},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(flag){
                
                if(flag){
                    window.location.href="Dashboard/index.jsp";//This page is target page.
                }else{
                    alert("FAIL");;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And when I clicked login button, I didn't get into new page instead page return a string to me like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaPfe.png)

I am new beginer, I will appreaciate whether your method works or not, as long as you answer it.

Comment: Hi, where `loginBtn` button , `username` inside your form and is your page refresh ?

Comment: yeah, I clicked login button and page refresh and return me string, can u help me?

Comment: You can use `event.preventDefault()` to stop your page refresh i.e : here change this `$("#loginBtn").click(function(event) {` then write `event.preventDefault()` see if that works .For more info check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347282/using-jquery-preventing-form-from-submitting) post.

Comment: w8w8w8, I mean I can't enter the next page, the page returns me a string, its mean something goes wrong. I want to click the button the page brings me to the next page, but seems like now it doesn't work. Just like in login function, I want to return datas to ajax in front end, but something worng in there.

Comment: I really need your help, it bothers me for couple of days.

Comment: You are using ajax so page should not get refresh that's the reason i told you to add that in my previous comment . I think your event is not getting just put `alert("in")` inside your `success:function(flag){`.. see if this show up ...

Comment: no, browser never gives me any alerts when clicked loginbtn. But when I added event.preventDefault(), the windows not get refreshed. OMG, that;s is problem.

Comment: Does there has one problem is that '$("#loginBtn").click(function(event)', the #loginBtn should be form's name instead btn's name?

Comment: no it should be button id which is been clicked.

Comment: wew, I already solved this problem, but there has another problem. Can I get you whatsapp？