how to display output using php ajax in jquery
Can you please tell me what is wrong with this code? It's not giving me any output after clicking submit.
$('#btnRun').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "libs/php/getCountryCode.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      lat: $('#lat1').val(),
      lng: $('#long1').val()
    },
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

      if (result.status.name == "ok") {
        $('try').html(result.data.countryCode);
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      // your error code
    }
  });
});

The result is obtained is this format:
{
  "languages": "de-AT,hr,hu,sl",
  "distance": "0",
  "countryCode": "AT",
  "countryName": "Austria"
}


Is your submit button possibly causing the page to be refreshed/redirected as part of the form submission? You most likely need to add a call to preventDefault() on the button click: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9347286/519413. Also your code is looking for a <try /> element which is unlikely to exist. Perhaps you meant to use $('.try') or $('#try')` instead

$('try').html(result.data.countryCode); can u replace try with an id something like #id or with a class like .id?
 $('#try').html(result.data.countryCode);

i tried $('#try').html(result.data.countryCode);      but its refreshing the page

e.preventDefault();
..
}```
give this a try

@JenaidaBarreto in that case see the link in my previous comment

$('#btnRun').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
url: "libs/php/getCountryCode.php",
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: {
lat: $('#lat1').val(),
lng: $('#long1').val()
},
success: function(result) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

if (result.status.name == "ok") {
 
   

 $('#try').html(result.data.countryCode);
 
 

}

},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
// your error code
}
});
});

i tried this but not working


Latitude: 

Longitude: 


Submit




<tr>
 <td>Results: </td>
 <td id="try">
  
 </td>

</tr>



is this code correct? index.html

can u console log the result.data and see what u r getting?

nothing showing in console

if i use this link : http://localhost/task/libs/php/getCountryCode.php?lat=47.03&lng=10.2      , then im getting this output in browser:  {
"status": {
"code": "200",
"name": "ok",
"description": "success",
"returnedIn": "335 ms"
},
"data": {
"languages": "de-AT,hr,hu,sl",
"distance": "0",
"countryCode": "AT",
"countryName": "Austria"
}
}

but html display not working

is the page getting refrshed when u submit?

is this php code correct? $decode = json_decode($result,true);
$output['status']['code'] = "200";
$output['status']['name'] = "ok";
$output['status']['description'] = "success";
$output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
$output['data'] = $decode;
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($output);

@rakesh, yes its getting refreshed

@rory i tried but ntng working

Can u try the below answer and see if it works?

@JenaidaBarreto then I'm afraid either you did it wrong, or there's an error in your page you need to debug

Try replacing your code with this and see if there are any logs
<form method="post">
  <label for="lat1">Latitude: </label>
  <input type="text" id="lat1">
  <label for="long1">Longitude: </label>
  <input type="text" id="long1">
  <br><br>
  <button id="btnRun" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>

$('#btnRun').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: "libs/php/getCountryCode.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      lat: $('#lat1').val(),
      lng: $('#long1').val()
    },
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

      if (result.status.name === "ok") {
        $('#try').html(result.data.countryCode);
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.error("Error: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
});


this works properly...thank you so much Rakesh..you saved my day.

$('#btnRun2').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
url: "libs/php/getOceanName.php",
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: {
lat: $('#lat2').val(),
lng: $('#long2').val()
},
success: function(result) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

if (result.status.name == "ok") {
 
   console.log(result.data);

 $('#ocn').html(result.data.name);
 
 

}

if(!result.data){
 $('#ocn').html(result.status.message);
}

},

how can i print message if data is null?
